# Create new array, after comparing chars of string & array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables, push

I have a `myArray = [A,C,D,G,J,L,P]`

and a `myString = "ABCDEF"`

I want to create a new array, containing only the characters of myString which can also be found in myArray, so that `myOtherArray = [A,C,D]`

I think the code should look something like this, but its not working yet.

```
for (int i=0; i<myString.length(); i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<myArray.length(); j++) {
    if ((myString.charAt(i)) == myArray[j]) {
      myOtherArray.push(myArray[j])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to run it in the console of your browser (or just check the error log), you will see that `int i=0` is wrong and `length` is not a function. Replace `int` with `var` (both) and `length()` with `length` (both), and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I check the error log? I'm writing in notepad, running in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `==` to test for equality.

```
if ((myString.charAt(i)) == myArray[j])
```

Also, it might be worth adding a `break` statement after pushing the letter. This makes the whole operation faster (albeit a micro-optimization if the arrays are small) and it also prevents the same letter being pushed twice if `myArray` contained duplicate entries.